# Symfony Creof FUNCTION mydbname.distance doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query, doctrine-extensions

I'm trying to use the Creof bundle and its Distance function. When I execute the following code, I get the following exception:

```
public function getMapDecorator(array $requestInformation, $type) : MapDecorator {
        $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Provider')->createQueryBuilder('provider');

    $point = new Point(0,0);
    $point->setLongitude($requestInformation["currentLongitude"]);
    $point->setLatitude($requestInformation["currentLatitude"]);

    // build the query
    $queryBuilder
        ->select('provider, DISTANCE(:point, provider.coordinates) AS HIDDEN distance')
        ->having('distance <= :radius')
        ->where("provider.type = :type")
        ->setParameter('type', $type)
        ->setParameter('radius', 10)
        ->setParameter('point', $point)
        ->orderBy('distance')
    ;

    $providers = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

    return null;
}
```

When executing this, this is the error I get

> "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT a0_.id AS id_0,
>   a0_.type AS type_1, AsBinary(a0_.coordinates) AS coordinates_2,
>   Distance(?, a0_.coordinates) AS sclr_3, a0_.path_id AS path_id_4,
>   a0_.coordinate_id AS coordinate_id_5 FROM provider a0_ WHERE a0_.type
>   = ? HAVING sclr_3 <= ? ORDER BY sclr_3 ASC' with params [{}, \"professional\", 10]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1305 FUNCTION mydbname.Distance does not exist"

I wonder why I'm getting this error, I can see debugging that this file is being called:           `CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Distance`

I also have the following in my configuration:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    dql:
        numeric_functions:
            # for mysql
            area:                   CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Area
            asbinary:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\AsBinary
            astext:                 CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\AsText
            buffer:                 CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Buffer
            centroid:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Centroid
            contains:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Contains
            crosses:                CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Crosses
            dimension:              CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Dimension
            distance:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Distance
            disjoint:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Disjoint
            distancefrommultyLine:  CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\DistanceFromMultyLine
            endpoint:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\EndPoint
            envelope:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Envelope
            equals:                 CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Equals
            exteriorring:           CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\ExteriorRing
            geodistpt:              CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\GeodistPt
            geometrytype:           CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\GeometryType
            geomfromtext:           CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\GeomFromText
            glength:                CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\GLength
            interiorringn:          CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\InteriorRingN
            intersects:             CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Intersects
            isclosed:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\IsClosed
            isempty:                CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\IsEmpty
            issimple:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\IsSimple
            linestringfromwkb:      CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\LineStringFromWKB
            linestring:             CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\LineString
            mbrcontains:            CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\MBRContains
            mbrdisjoint:            CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\MBRDisjoint
            mbrequal:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\MBREqual
            mbrintersects:          CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\MBRIntersects
            mbroverlaps:            CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\MBROverlaps
            mbrtouches:             CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\MBRTouches
            mbrwithin:              CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\MBRWithin
            numinteriorrings:       CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\NumInteriorRings
            numpoints:              CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\NumPoints
            overlaps:               CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Overlaps
            pointfromwkb:           CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\PointFromWKB
            pointn:                 CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\PointN
            point:                  CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Point
            srid:                   CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\SRID
            startpoint:             CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\StartPoint
            st_buffer:              CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STBuffer
            st_contains:            CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STContains
            st_crosses:             CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STCrosses
            st_disjoint:            CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STDisjoint
            st_equals:              CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STEquals
            st_intersects:          CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STIntersects
            st_overlaps:            CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STOverlaps
            st_touches:             CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STTouches
            st_within:              CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STWithin
            touches:                CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Touches
            within:                 CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Within
            x:                      CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\X
            y:                      CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Found the issue. Mysql deprecated the Distance function in favor of ST_Distance. This bundle should update that but for the time being, I created the following class in my bundle:

```
namespace AppBundle\ORM;

use CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\AbstractSpatialDQLFunction;

/**
 * Distance DQL function
 *
 * @author  luca capra <luca.capra@create-net.org>
 * @license http://dlambert.mit-license.org MIT
 */
class STDistance extends AbstractSpatialDQLFunction {

    protected $platforms = array('mysql');
    protected $functionName = 'ST_Distance';
    protected $minGeomExpr = 2;
    protected $maxGeomExpr = 2;

}
```

and I added that in my config:

```
st_distance:            AppBundle\ORM\STDistance
```

and I now use `ST_Distance` instead of `Distance`